# How to call multiple ajax request using console log

Tags: ajax, console

How can i call multiple time ajax request using on console log.

i have Reply XHR to working fine but i need multiple request send using console log. any idea?

Comment: Why are you trying to make ajax requests in a console.log call? This is normally as the name says for logging to the console in dev tools.

Comment: Using console.log in i will set timeInterval and call multiple time ajax request.. i am testing using console log my counter number increased or not that's why i need @Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you loop looks something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   $.ajax({
    //
    success:function(data){
       $("#p" + i + "_points").html(data);
    }
   });
}
it will not work as i will end up being the last i value in the loop; You need something like below

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   (function(index){
      $.ajax({
       //
       success:function(data){
          $("#p" + index + "_points").html(data);
       }
      });
   })(i);
}
The closure along with the passing of i will keep number value for that call.

of course there will need to exist elements with ids 1-10 or whatever number you use so:

<element id="p1_points">
<element id="p2_points">
<element id="p3_points">
...
```